# Sonicwall re-direct to login page

Tags: sonicwall, authentication

I have the firewall LAN > WAN rule in place to require trusted users before allowing http, https, and dns. This allows redirecting to the login page for user authentication when the user visits http://example.com.

My issue is when a user visits https://example.com, they are not redirected to the login page but are given a network reset error. This is causing our users to think the internet is down rather than they need to login.

How can I set up a rule to redirect all unauthenticated users to https://login.mysonicwall when they visit an https website before http?

I thought [this article](https://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/ext/kbdetail.aspx?kbid=10272&SearchType=advanced&referrer=&status=&rfield=&sortmethod=datemodified&usertype=&subcats=True&start=51&match=or&catid=143&formaction=amq&viewguid=08A09FAA-34B1-498F-AF9E-95EDBF539011) would work for https, but it did not. I do have DPI-SSL license for this Sonicwall.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to allow DNS through.  Without DNS resolution, the http(s) requests will not finish and trigger the redirect to the login page.  What I did was add a rule that permitted DNS for All as the first rule, then everything else permitted for Trusted Users.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP and HTTPS are different protocols. Redirecting port 80 to port 443 would mean that clients are trying to talk HTTP on port 443, which fails because the server is expecting them to talk HTTPS. You need to do a redirect in HTTP using a 301 or 302 redirect code.

Comment: The clients are already talking in https. The problem is not http to https.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this, it sounds like you are working with SSLVPN for SonicWALL. This, and the login page are the only things SonicWALL uses a redirect rule for. If this is what you are having trouble with and you have licensed you SonicWALL, you should contact SonicWALL support. I have always received world class support from them and they can help you locate the issue in your specific case. I can't speak highly enough of their support.